# Connect two routers using wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge

I am following this advice [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Routers#Using-Wireless). I have not managed to setup the secondary router yet.

I don't see how what configuration here actually connects you to the primary router. I WPA-Personal on the primary router that is why I used the same on the secondary. I was assuming you have to specify the address of the primary router, but that is only done through local address here (192.168.1.1), I thought you cannot access this address if you are not in the network?

Interesting enough the [documentation](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) of my firmware tells the secondary router should have the same SSID as the first while the aforementioned tutorial tells the oposite that you should specify an unique SSID.

Comment: In the Wireless (second) Section of the first article you posted says  " Determine if your equipment is compatible.[4] While most wireless routers can be used as wireless access points (also known as range extenders), most retail routers cannot be used to create their own network inside of the primary router's network.[5]

    In order to create a separate wireless network within the primary router's network, your secondary router must have "bridge" or "repeater" mode capabilities.
    Your router's documentation will let you know if it has bridge mode. "  Be sure this is true.

Comment: My router has  bridge repeater capabilities, infact that is the setting I chose. However I should somewhere specify what network to connect to don't you think?

Comment: So are you saying access point (same SSID), repeater (different SSID)

Comment: I would follow each detail of the Wireless Section and make sure of the IP addresses and gateway addresses you use.

Comment: You need to set Repeater mode and yes I would use different SSIDs so you can identify the two boxes

Comment: So the Secondary can access the primary via the local IP 192.168.1.1(the default gateway of the primary?)

Comment: No. The secondary needs to use an IP on the main, not the gateway address. That will not work. I would use a Static IP such as 192.168.1.4 assuming the main is not .4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for repeater bridge mode each participant of the network must have his own unique IP

that mean, you should have only one DHCP enabled for that mode (recommended)

that mean, you should have only one SSID

a typical setup could look like

```
SSID home
192.168.1.1 (Gateway) DHCP + WLAN Access Point Router 1
192.168.1.50-200 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool
192.168.1.10 (static IP) WLAN repeater bridge Router 2
192.168.1.20 (static IP) WLAN repeater bridge Router 3
```

all share the same network 192.168.1.xxx  255.255.255.0 and use 192.168.1.1 Gateway + DNS. the WAN Port is disabled on repeaters. (you can however split DHCP ranges, but lets keep it simple)

for client mode you can separate networks, if for some reason you want have each Router it's own pool

```
SSID home
192.168.1.1 (Gateway) DHCP + WLAN Access Point Router 1
192.168.1.50-100 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool

SSID floor 1
192.168.1.10 (static IP) WAN Router 2
192.168.10.10 (static IP) WLAN Client + vAP Router 2
192.168.10.100-150 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool

SSID floor 2
192.168.10.20 (static IP) WAN Router 3
192.168.100.20 (static IP) WLAN Client + vAP Router 3
192.168.100.150-200 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool
```

each router has its own network 192.168.xxx.xxx. the WAN Port is connected as client into the APs network, while DHCP has it's own range. now each client router has two IP addresses, one as client in WAN and one as Gateway in DHCP Range
to make this work wireless, each client router has additional (virtual) AP with different SSID enabled (client SSID remains/must be the one from Router 1/ Router 2)

the above example is of course simplified, but no need to stick on that ip. you can of course use the full range for each network, like

```
SSID home
192.168.1.1 (Gateway) DHCP + WLAN Access Point Router 1
192.168.1.3-250 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool

SSID floor 1
192.168.1.2 (static IP) WAN Router 2
192.168.10.1 (static IP) WLAN Client + vAP Router 2
192.168.10.3-250 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool

SSID floor 2
192.168.10.2 (static IP) WAN Router 3
192.168.100.1 (static IP) WLAN Client + vAP Router 3
192.168.100.2-250 (DHCP) ethernet/WLAN client pool
```

Comment: https://i1.wp.com/www.tuluzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cascade_networks.png

Comment: From the first setup: 192.168.1.1 (Gateway) DHCP + WLAN Access Point Router 1 is this the adress of the primary WIFI router. I thought the gateway was the adress of the modem from which you get internet.

Comment: you are right. i am talking about so called *"home box"* ([residential wireless gateway](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residential_gateway)) which is in real multiple hardware all-in-one

Comment: Do you know how to get the address of the wifi router. presumably the default gateway in  IPconfig point to the ethernet modem?

Comment: No worries I figured out my wifi router has 192.168.0.1 which get internet from modem the adress there is 192.168.1.2.